# iphone Slide Menu using iOS-Slide-Menu

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Hello everyone I try to use https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu as slide menu for one of my viewcontroller. I read the documentation about slide menu, and here is my appdelegate class, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application       
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[StyleKit setupAppearance];

ListViewController *controller = [ListViewController new];
    _navigationController  = [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithRootViewController:controller];
RightViewController *rightMenu = [RightViewController new];

[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = rightMenu;
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].menuRevealAnimationDuration = .18;
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window.rootViewController = _navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidClose object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Closed %@", menu);
}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidOpen object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Opened %@", menu);
}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidReveal object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Revealed %@", menu);
}];
return YES;
}
```

I want to show slide menu in "ListViewController" so as documentation said i implemented my header file like this:

```
//
//  ListViewController.h

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "SlideNavigationController.h"
 @interface ListViewController :         
 UIViewController<SlideNavigationControllerDelegate>
 @end
// ListViewController.m
//Some code...
- (void)setupActions {
[self.listView.tableHeaderView.followButton addTarget:self"                                       
 action:@selector(didTapFollowButton:)                          
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.fakeNavigationController.menuButton addTarget:  
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance]   
action:@selector(toggleRightMenu)   
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
  {
    return NO;
  }

   - (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayRightMenu
  {
  return YES;
 }
```

But when I start app I get this error:
SlideNavigationController has not been initialized. Either place one in your storyboard or initialize one in code.

Please waiting for your helps, thanks   s:)

Comment: have you added view controller in your storyBoard ? if no then add it and set it as initial view controller

Comment: I have no storyboard... @ravi.p

Answer (score 0):

**Main Point** You have to give **isinitViewController** to your **SlideNavigationController**

Import this line in **AppDelegate.h** file

```
#import "SlideNavigationController.h"
#import "LeftMenuViewController.h"
#import "RightMenuViewController.h" 


 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    RightMenuViewController *rightMenu = (RightMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                           instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"RightMenuViewController"];
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = rightMenu;
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].menuRevealAnimationDuration = .18;
// Creating a custom bar button for right menu
    UIButton *button  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] action:@selector(toggleRightMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidClose object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
        NSLog(@"Closed %@", menu);
    }];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidOpen object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
        NSLog(@"Opened %@", menu);
    }];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidReveal object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
        NSLog(@"Revealed %@", menu);
    }];
  return YES;
}
```

In your HomeController put this delegates method

## pragma mark - SlideNavigationController Methods -

```
- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
{
    return false;
}

- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayRightMenu
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Actually, my homecontroller is not my initial view controller, I mean: The controller that i want to add slide view is no initial view controller

Comment: in your storyborad the initial view controller you must give a SlideNavigationController and then your next controller thats your first controller like any UIVIewController .

Comment: I dont use storyboard.

Comment: In your appdelegate method, Try to add one navigation controller and set class of navigation controller as slidenavigationcontroller and then navigate from this controller to your view controller.

Comment: So,is my main navigation controller going to be slidenavigationcontroller? @Jecky

Comment: yeah, you have to set

Comment: can you write it as a clear answer so I can vote you up :)

Comment: Wait I will check @HimanshuMoradiya code and will update it as per your requirement or will post new answer